# Objective-C cash register text

Tags: objective-c

I'm working on an iOS app that will incorporate a cash register. I need to be able to type in numbers and have the decimal point stay in place just like a real cash register.

An example of the code being used presently is:

```
-(IBAction)Number1:(id)sender{
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber * 10;
    SelectNumber = SelectNumber + 1;
    Screen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", SelectNumber];
}
```

So for example you would start with:

```
0.00
```

You then press 1

```
0.01
```

You then press 2 then 3

```
1.23
```

Then a five

```
12.35
```

Currently if I do this I would end up going from 0.00 to 1235 (no decimal)

I have no idea how to accomplish this and my googling has thus far failed me.  Any ideas / solutions?

Comment: I think you'll need to write a custom view.

Comment: it would be helpful if you'd show us how you display it.

Comment: @trojanfoe, not needed. OP will be able to achieve it with NSNumberFormatter and simple UILabel.

Comment: @vikingosegundo That will look crap and unless he uses a fixed-width font, the decimal point will always move.

Comment: so first he will have to explain what "in-place" means. at the same pixel, or between the 2nd and 3rd digit right hand side.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  vikinggosegundo - I've added an example of the actions used.

Comment: @vikingosegundo He already has: like a cash register.  I understand what he wants from his question.

Comment: no, he hasn't. like a cash register can mean several things already. it could be separated digit, as you seem to understand, or a format like "$ 0.01" as I understand.

Comment: His question demonstrates what he wants.  There is no `$` in his question; he just wants entry to behave as if digits come from right to left as they are entered, with the decimal point remaining at the same location.

Comment: the $ was just eye candy. the question is: is it just the format, or will he need to print the digits on different labels.

Comment: @ScottRowley: maybe this code will help you: https://github.com/vikingosegundo/VSClickWheel  try the example target. here is a post in my blog http://blog.vikingosegundo.de/2013/08/23/input-element-not-only-possibly-big-numbers/ it is mainly about the input ement, but it contains code for handling digits in a string.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, thanks for the link.  Just a note though, your "Result" image is missing :(

Comment: Interesting, I tried opening it in a new tab from it's source but it still shows nothing for me. Oh well, I'll leave you to do with it as you will ;)

http://blog.vikingosegundo.de/media/uploads/vsclickwheel1.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create method to display number in the format you want:

```
-(NSMutableString*)displayNumber:(NSString*)str {

    NSMutableString *myNumber = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%03d", [str intValue]];
    [myNumber insertString:@"." atIndex:myNumber.length-2];
    return myNumber;
}
```

And you can create mutable string to represent the number and just append another number and use displayNumber method to display it in the format you want:

```
NSMutableString *number = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];
NSLog(@"%@", [self displayNumber:number]); // 0.00
[number appendString:@"2"];
NSLog(@"%@", [self displayNumber:number]); //0.02
[number appendString:@"3"];
NSLog(@"%@", [self displayNumber:number]); //0.23
[number appendString:@"1"];
NSLog(@"%@", [self displayNumber:number]); //23.1
[number appendString:@"5"];
NSLog(@"%@", [self displayNumber:number]); //23.15
```

You should handle some validation to make sure that user add just numeric value.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an [`NSDecimalNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/nsdecimalnumber_class/reference/reference.html).
Here are the basic ingredients:

1. A mutable string to hold the digits that the user inputs
2. An `NSDecimalNumber` to hold the actual number
3. An `NSNumberFormatter` to present the number in the UI

---

```
// Our properties
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDecimalNumber *accumulator;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *accumulatorString;

// Initial values
_accumulator = [NSDecimalNumber zero];
_accumulatorString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"0"];
_numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
_numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle;
_numberFormatter.currencySymbol = @"$"; 
// You might want to adjust the formatter depending on the locale
// Here is a minimal setup just for the purpose of this example

// The user taps a number
// Of course the digit will be provided dynamically
// (something like [sender currentTitle] for example
// would be ok for a numeric keypad scenario)
[self.accumulatorString appendString:@"6"]; 

// Update our decimal number
// Here if our string is '06' with mantissa -2 => 0.06
// string '061' with mantissa -2 => 0.61 and so on...
self.accumulator = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMantissa:[self.accumulatorString integerValue]
                                                     exponent:-2
                                                   isNegative:NO];

// Update the display
self.myDisplayLabel.text = [self.numberFormatter stringFromNumber:self.accumulator];
```

Comment: Beyond currency symbol, NSNumberFormatter gets a lot from the current locale: `en_US` = $1,234.56, `fr_FR = 1 234,56 $` `ar_EG = ١٢٣٤٫٥٦ $`.  Depending on context, you will want to force an locale.

Comment: @BrianNickel Agreed, but I think that is beyond the scope of this example. I will note it on the comments though. Thanks!